# How to detect an image between shapes from camera

Tags: objective-c, opencv, image-processing, xamarin.ios, contour

I've been searching around the web about how to do this and I know that it needs to be done with OpenCV. The problem is that all the tutorials and examples that I find are for separated shapes detection or template matching.

What I need is a way to detect the contents between 3 circles (which can be a photo or something else). From what I searched, its not to difficult to find the circles with the camera using contours but, how do I extract what is between them? The circles work like a pattern on the image to grab what is "inside the pattern".

Do I need to use the contours of each circle and measure the distance between them to grab my contents? If so, what if the image is a bit rotated/distorted on the camera?

I'm using Xamarin.iOS for this but from what I already saw, I believe I need to go native for this and any Objective C example is welcome too.

**EDIT**

Imagining that the image captured by the camera is this:

[image: Image captured by camera]

What I want is to match the 3 circles and get the following part of the image as result:

[image: Result after matching the circles]

Since the images come from the camera, they can be rotated or scaled up/down.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "between circles".

Comment: Please check the edit I made to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `warpAffine` function will let you map the desired area of the source image to a destination image, performing cropping, rotation and scaling in a single go.

Talking about rotation and scaling seem to indicate that you want to extract a rectangle of a given aspect ratio, hence perform a *similarity* transform. To define such a transform, three points are too much, two suffice. The construction of the affine matrix is a little tricky.